# Is there a way to initialize a JSM Serializer manually?

Tags: php, json, symfony, dependency-injection, jms-serializer

I'm writing a PHP wrapper project for an API. Within my response object, I like to deserialize a JSON block to an object. It is not a symfony standard framework project, just a PHP project with symfony components.

Within a symfony project I would simply call

```
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
```

and be done with it. But of course my class is neither ContainerAware nor has any kind of access to a container or services in general. I need to use the JMS Serializer as the API I'm writing the wrapper for also used the JMS Serializer (with configurations).

Is there a way to initialize a JMS Serializer (`JMS\Serializer\Serializer`) manually?

Within the services.xml of the JMS Serializer there is the following definition:

```
<service id="jms_serializer.serializer" class="%jms_serializer.serializer.class%" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="jms_serializer.metadata_factory" />
    <argument type="service" id="jms_serializer.handler_registry" />
    <argument type="service" id="jms_serializer.object_constructor" />
    <argument type="collection" /><!-- Serialization Visitors -->
    <argument type="collection" /><!-- Deserialization Visitors -->
    <argument type="service" id="jms_serializer.event_dispatcher" />
</service>

...

<service id="jms_serializer.metadata_factory" class="%jms_serializer.metadata.metadata_factory.class%" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="jms_serializer.metadata.lazy_loading_driver" />
    <argument>Metadata\ClassHierarchyMetadata</argument>
    <argument />
    <call method="setCache">
        <argument type="service" id="jms_serializer.metadata.cache" on-invalid="ignore" />
    </call>
</service>

...

<service id="jms_serializer.metadata.lazy_loading_driver" class="%jms_serializer.metadata.lazy_loading_driver.class%" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    <argument>jms_serializer.metadata_driver</argument>
</service>

...
```

I could initialize one object after the other but I would still be stuck at the point where the Service Container (`<argument type="service" id="service_container" />`) is required.

Is there still a way to initialize the JMS Serializer manually?

Comment: So your project is only using S2 components and not the S2 framework?

Comment: Yes, exactly (I updated the question)

Comment: I suspect it will be a painful process at best.  If you really can't use the framework then build on top of the Symfony\Serializer component.

Comment: I guessed that it will be painful, but at the moment I don't even know whether and if how it is possible.

Comment: And I need to use the JMS Serializer as the API I'm writing the wrapper for also uses the JMS Serializer (and many of it's configurations) to serialize the data to JSON. (updated the question)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/doc/configuration.rst

Comment: I just stumbled over this myself a second ago : ) Could you put the link as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The services file you are looking at comes from the Symfony 2 framework specific JMSSerializerBundle.

The bundle itself is just a thin wrapper to the generic JMS serializer package code.

The package documentation will get you going: https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/tree/master/doc

The construction part can be found here:
https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/doc/configuration.rst